# Find regular expression for a binary sequence dividable by 3

Tags: computational-mathematics

I am trying to find a short regular expression that matches to all binary sequences that are dividable by 3.

This is homework. It would be great if I could only get some hints before the final solution :D

Using the DFA I would get the following states

```
 |0|1
A|A|B
B|C|A
C|B|C
```

That would give

$$A=0A+1B\\
B=0C+1A\\
C=0B+1C
$$

I eliminate the recursion of $1C$ which is $1*$ and $0A$ which is $0*$

$$
A=0*+1B\\
B=0C+1A\\
C=0B+1*$$

I replace C in B

$$B=0(0B+1*)+1A$$

I need to get rid of the $0B$ somehow to be able to place it into A. $0B$ part should be again a recurision.. But I am lost from here on.

Any hints?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Won't  you get $C=1^*0B$ from $C=0B+1C$?

Comment: Hm not sure? But union is commutativ so could be $1*+0B$ so the + can be removed?

Comment: There is a shorter version $(1(01*0)*1|0)+$ which I try to get to

Answer (score 0):

From $C=0B+1C$ we have
$$ C = 1^*0B $$
Then $B=0C+1A$ becomes $B=1^*0B+1A$, from which he find
$$ B = (1^*0)^*1A$$
Now $A=0A+1B+\epsilon$ becomes $A= 0A+(1^*0)^*1A +\epsilon= (0 | (1^*0)^*1)A+\epsilon $ and from this ultimately
$$A=(0 | (1^*0)^*1)^*$$
(or with the last $^*$ replaced with $^+$ if you want to avoid $\epsilon$ as match)

Comment: how did you get from $B=1∗0B+1A$ to $B=(1∗0)∗1A$?